# Is it possible to instantiate polymorphic piece of code differently in the same function?

Tags: haskell

OK, I don't see how it can be done, but knowing that Haskell is a language of infinite depth, I decided to ask this here before giving up.

Suppose we have a value that is polymorphic, for example:

```
foo :: Monad m => m Int
foo = return Int
```

Obviously, depending on context, `m` can be instantiated to different types. I wonder if it's possible now to take this abstract piece of code and use it in several different contexts inside the same function (for example to reduce boilerplate when covering code):

```
bar :: Monad m => m Int -> Property
bar m = conjoin
  [ checkIt (runIdentityT m)
  , checkIt (runReaderT m ())
  , …
  ]
```

Where `checkIt` accepts some concrete monad. Since `foo` is essentially abstract description how to do something, it should be possible to use it in several contexts, but the problem is obviously that if we promise to work with any `Monad m => m Int` in signature of `bar`, then we cannot write this function on less abstract level since then it's not possible to accommodate to every possible instance of `Monad` in its implementation.

---

Is there a way to pass `foo` into `bar` so it can be used in several type contexts inside it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want rank-2 types:

```
bar :: (forall m. Monad m => m Int) -> Property
bar m = conjoin
  [ checkIt (runIdentityT m)
  , checkIt (runReaderT m ())
  , …
  ]
```

Now, `bar foo` will type check.

Concretely, the type `(forall m. Monad m => m Int)` requires the argument to be *polymorphic* and usable for *all* monads `m`. By comparison, the original type

```
bar :: Monad m => m Int -> Property
```

only requires the argument to have a type of the form `m Int` for *some* monad `m`. In your case, you clearly want "for all", and not "for some".

You can enable rank-2 types by putting at the top of your file the following line:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
```

---

On a more theoretical note, my guts are telling me that the type

```
(forall m. Monad m => m Int)
```

is actually isomorphic to

```
Int
```

with isomorphisms:

```
iso :: Int -> (forall m. Monad m => m Int)
iso x = return x

osi :: (forall m. Monad m => m Int) -> Int
osi m = runIdentity m
```

The above should indeed be an isomorphism thanks to the free theorem associated to `forall m. Monad m => m Int`.

If my intuition is correct, as I believe, this means that every value of the type `forall m. Monad m => m Int` *has* to have the form `return x` for some integer `x`.

So, the final counter-question is: why don't you simply pass an `Int`, and remove the unneeded rank-2 machinery?

Comment: Ironically, I tried this before writing the question, but although it indeed type-checked, I had trouble using it because of `couldn't match type f0 with m because type variable m would escape its scope` errors. It still does not work even with the `Rank2Types` exnension.

Comment: Re update: In real code it's more complex, there is no conrete types like `Int`.

Comment: Can you post more code? It's impossible to guess what you really need.

Comment: @Mark A wild guess: this is about megaparsec's `ParsecT`, right?

Comment: OK, I'm sort of ashamed that I couldn't handle this myself and that I really cannot come up with simplified version of this. So here is real `bar`: https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec/blob/improving-coverage/tests/Util.hs#L84-L100 and here is where I want to use it and I'm getting that error message: https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec/blob/improving-coverage/tests/Prim.hs#L334 . I know how `forall` works, but here I'm facing something that is not obvious for me, at least now.

Comment: @Mark: `forall m s . MonadParsec s m Char =>`. The choice of the monad _is_ arbitrary, but the type of text isn't due to `char` in the actual test (you'll also need `p :: MonadParsec s m Char => m String`).

Comment: @Zeta, thanks, explicit type annotation made all the difference.